# AOSP how to use 32 bits native library in APK

Tags: android, java-native-interface, android-source

I have 64-bit Android device, which is running on Android 7.

I have some native library which I build inside in AOSP. I build two versions of this lib 32-bits and 64-bits.

In the app I'm using

```
System.loadLibrary(libraryname)
```

App tries to find library in system/lib64/ vendor/lib64

But I should use 32 bits library. 
What variable should I set in mk file of app, in order to use 32 bits version of library?

Comment: Have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/q/27712921/603270 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/29329413/603270 ?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't help